# Prestashop SEO & URLs section is blank

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a Prestashop 1.6 website. When I navigate to Preferences -> SEO & URLs section the page is blank. No options are visible on that page. I've enabled _PS_MODE_DEV_ and still it is not showing the error.

Please suggest if someone experienced the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some invalid class declarations which cause fatal error (possibly before the config is loaded).

What you can do is trace the line of the error by repeatedly inserting `die('here');` statement while moving up the excuted code - start from `index.php`.

I have experience a case like this myself and there was no way to find the error but to move up the code yourself